# python import fails for some methods

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I'm seeing very strange error with my python module. It throws `ImportError` for one method. It imports other methods.

`main.py`

```py
   from utils import func1, func2, func3
   ...
```

`utils.py`

```py
   def func1():
    ...
   def func2():
    ...
   def func3():
   ...
```

The `ImportError` shows up for `func3`. Both `main.py` and `utils.py` are in same directory (it's not a package).

I'm using `func3` as decorator in `main.py`, but I guess that shouldn't matter for this error.

I defined new methods (`func4` etc) and imported them in main. `ImportError` is thrown on all new methods. Only `func1` and `func2` are successfully imported.

If anyone has ideas to debug, that'll be helpful

Comment: Is this in IDLE?

Comment: what is the error , add that also

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the full error trace.

Comment: do either `func1` or `func2` have `import` statements within their scope ?

Comment: Delete all pyc files or caches, exit all repls, try again?

Comment: Thanks all for quick responses. This is a production code and let me get a minimal reproducible example first. Will close the question until then.